# Generate a list of lists that add to a given int (game of Nim)

Tags: python, list, int, minimax

I am new to Python/Computing science - (and also to this site). I tried to search this up but couldn't find how to do it. This is part of a assignment that I have to do. (Game of Nim).

Basically, I have to split a given integer number (e.g: 6) into it's all possible combinations that can add to it, in a list of lists - but NOT duplicates.

So, for example, for 6, the function would generate: [[1,5],[2,4]]
for 10, it would generate: [[9,1],[8,2],[7,3],[6,4]]

(I would then use these to "dissect" them more, using a binary tree, but I think I can do that myself - just need help on this part)

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Your two examples have different orders: the first increasing, the second decreasing. Which order do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cab be one of the possible helper function.

```
# python 3.x
def solution(number):
    return [[i, number - i] for i in range(number // 2 + 1)]

>>>solution(6)
[[0, 6], [1, 5], [2, 4], [3, 3]]

>>>solution(10)
[[0, 10], [1, 9], [2, 8], [3, 7], [4, 6], [5, 5]]
```

Comment: Thanks ! easy solution. But I forgot to add that the zero entries should not be there, but all good!

Comment: @VimM you can change `range(number // 2 + 1)` to `range(1, number // 2 + 1)` which will start loop from `1` instead of `0`.

Comment: `[3,3]` shouldn't be here either

Answer (score 0):

Simple Example:

```
n = 6
l = 0
r = n
lista = []
while l<=r:
    if l+r == n:
        lista.append((l,r))
    l += 1
    r -= 1
print lista

#Output
[(0, 6), (1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 3)]
```

and to remove duplicates, you can use `set()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
n = 6
lst = [[i, n-i] for i in range(n)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want duplicates, you could stop at the middle, making sure it works for both odd and even numbers with :

```
[(i, n - i) for i in range(1, (n + 1) // 2)]
```

Here's an example :

```
>>> n=6
>>> [(i, n - i) for i in range(1, (n + 1) // 2)]
[(1, 5), (2, 4)]
>>> n=7
>>> [(i, n - i) for i in range(1, (n + 1) // 2)]
[(1, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4)]
>>> n=10
>>> [(i, n - i) for i in range(1, (n + 1) // 2)]
[(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, 6)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your time!

Comment: @VimM : You're welcome. Note that this method returns exactly what you wanted : no `(0,6)` and no `(3,3)` either.